# Do we ever find out what happened when Gary Parsons hit a woman with his car?

Tags: character, plot-explanation, damages

In the show [Damages](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0914387/), in [Season 1, Episode 8](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1003360/), Ellen Parsons takes some time away from the main plot to help her father with a civil suit in which he hit a woman with his car. The last we hear of it, her mother is worried that they are going to have to pay a million dollars in damages because the woman will never work again.

It's never mentioned again for the rest of the season. [According to IMDB, Ellen's father only makes two more appearances in the rest of the show, in Seasons 3 and 5, one episode each](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0369760/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t112).

It was kind of jarring that such a major case just never seems to come up again. Does this ever get explained later on? I'm only in Season 2. Did the writers ever talk about why it never came up again?